# Convert SQL inner join query to Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hey I have problem with Convert this SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT izo_client.name
FROM izo_client
INNER JOIN izo_measurement
ON izo_client.id=izo_measurement.client_id;
```

into Doctrine query builder

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('u')
            ->from('AppBundle:Client', 'u')
            ->innerJoin('AppBundle:Measurement', 'm', 'WITH', 'u.id = m.client_id')
            ->distinct();

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The error is:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'client_id': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Measurement has no field or association named client_id
```

Comment: How does your Measurement class look like? Specifically, does it have a client_id field  or clientId perhaps?

Comment: It has field $clientsBelongsTo which looks like:
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="measurements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="To pole nie może być puste")
     */
    private $clientBelongsTo;

Comment: ok when i change m.client_id to m.clientBelongsTo it works. I forgot to operate on class fields, not table fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DQL is not an SQL. In DQL you operate on objects, not database relations. Properties are used as opposed to database columns.

Since your field is called `$clientsBelongsTo`, your query should look more like:

```php
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle:Client', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:Measurement', 'm', 'WITH', 'u.id = m.clientsBelongsTo')
    ->distinct();
```